# Magnetic field and amperes circuital law

Tags: electromagnetism

I have applied amperes circuital law to an infinite wire. But if I apply the same rule to a finite wire then also the condition will be same. In a circular path of some radial  distance from wire field will be same and direction of field at every pointon the amperian circukar loop will be parallel to the loop direction. This is same condition which we found in infinite wire case. Then if we apply law
Then field comes out be same. but the field depends on the angle of elevation and depression of the end points of wire. I think that I am missing something. Can someone resolve my problem and tell me where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

When applying Ampere's law, you need to consider the fact that the current must flow in a loop and cannot solely exist in a finite piece of the wire. For example, if you had only a finite piece of current-carrying wire, you could choose your surface such that it still has the same circular boundary but doesn't intersect the wire. This would mean the integral of the magnetic field along the boundary is zero: clearly a contradiction. Because of the rest of the circuit, the magnetic field isn't axially symmetric about the wire in general, and applying Ampere's law is usually not trivial.

In a problem like this where you can't exploit symmetries, the Biot-Savart law is usually more useful in evaluating the magnetic field at a given point.

Comment: Sir, But from biot savarts law magnitude of field comes to be same in all direction at a given radial distance and is tangential to that point. So now if amperes circuital law is applied than field is constant in the loop. And if we apply here than result coming is same as for field due to infinite wire case. Please sir explain in some detail.

Comment: Again, you need to consider the circuit the wire is connected to when evaluating the magnetic field, even when using the Biot-Savart law, because the current cannot exist solely in a finite piece of wire. When applying the Biot-Savart law, you will find that the current flowing in this circuit contributes to the magnetic field integral.

Comment: If I have to consider the whole circuit in ampere circuital law than why don't we consider the whole circuit while evaluating Magnetic field using biot savarts law . Then we just consider the piece of wire, and assume that current is just flowing in the wire.

Comment: You do need to consider the whole circuit when applying the Biot-Savart law. In certain cases the contribution from the rest of the circuit may be small enough to be neglected (e.g. when you are evaluating the magnetic field very close to the wire), but not always.

Comment: If the contribution due to rest circuit may be neglected then why you said that while applying amperes circuits law we need to consider the field due to rest circuit. In ideal condition we can also neglect the contribution due to the rest circuit here also. Please sir explain in detail I am just a school student.

Comment: If the contribution from the rest of the circuit can be neglected, that would probably mean you are either very close to the wire or the wire is very long, in which case the magnetic field would be roughly the same as that of an infinitely long wire anyway. There is no obvious way to calculate the magnetic field purely due to the wire other than with the Biot-Savart law, but even then the actual (total) magnetic field is different. There is no clear way to ignore part of the circuit and expect Ampere's law to make sense, it differs from the Biot-Savart law in this way.